# "public_activity" timelines /feed/log activity gem : how to do permanent saving of timelines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, feed

when destroying one element from my database, the index view

```
      <% for activity in @activities %>

      <%= activity.text %>  by  <%= current_user.name %> on <%= Time.current%> <br/>


    <% end %>
```

no longer find the <%=trackable.element_name%> from config/pba.yml

```
    activity:
        element:
              create: '  <%=trackable.element_name%> has been created '
              update: '  <%=trackable.element_name%> has been edited '
             destroy: '  <%=trackable.element_name%> has been removed '
```

and display something like:

```
    element1 has been edited by me on 2012-08-19 16:20:44 UTC
  Template not defined by me on 2012-08-19 16:20:44 UTC
```

"template not defined" being the element i have just deleted....

i would like to store the element name and the action that has been taken though...!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I released a new version of the `public_activity` gem which allows you to create views for every activity you display, so you can simply check if `trackable` is still in the database and act accordingly.

Upgrade your gem to https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity#upgrading-to-04 and check out my example application which does exactly that:

https://github.com/pokonski/activity_blog/blob/master/app/views/public_activity/post/_update.slim#L4

where link_to_trackable is just a helper checking if trackable exists: https://github.com/pokonski/activity_blog/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb#L34

Comment: About a month ago, a [Railscast on Public Activity](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) was released. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it can't find the original element you deleted. Have you thought of using soft-delete? The record remains in the database.